# Flutter print the color name

Tags: flutter, dart

Is there a way to print the actual color name in Flutter. For example, my color is  `final myColor= Colors.green`
so when I print the color such that `print(myColor);` I want to see the color name as ***green***, not the HEX value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This package does exactly that:

https://pub.dev/packages/color_parser

you can use it like this

```
print( ColorParser.color(Colors.green).toName() ) ;
```

Answer (score 0):

I needed the color from the name string, so i created a map.

```dart
static const Map<String, Color> colorStringToColor = {
    'amber': Colors.amber,
    'amberAccent': Colors.amberAccent,
    'black': Colors.black,
    'black12': Colors.black12,
    'black26': Colors.black26,
    'black38': Colors.black38,
    'black45': Colors.black45,
    'black54': Colors.black54,
    'black87': Colors.black87,
    'blue': Colors.blue,
    'blueAccent': Colors.blueAccent,
    'blueGrey': Colors.blueGrey,
    'brown': Colors.brown,
    'cyan': Colors.cyan,
    'cyanAccent': Colors.cyanAccent,
    'deepOrange': Colors.deepOrange,
    'deepOrangeAccent': Colors.deepOrangeAccent,
    'deepPurple': Colors.deepPurple,
    'deepPurpleAccent': Colors.deepPurpleAccent,
    'green': Colors.green,
    'greenAccent': Colors.greenAccent,
    'grey': Colors.grey,
    'indigo': Colors.indigo,
    'indigoAccent': Colors.indigoAccent,
    'lightBlue': Colors.lightBlue,
    'lightBlueAccent': Colors.lightBlueAccent,
    'lightGreen': Colors.lightGreen,
    'lightGreenAccent': Colors.lightGreenAccent,
    'lime': Colors.lime,
    'limeAccent': Colors.limeAccent,
    'orange': Colors.orange,
    'orangeAccent': Colors.orangeAccent,
    'pink': Colors.pink,
    'pinkAccent': Colors.pinkAccent,
    'purple': Colors.purple,
    'purpleAccent': Colors.purpleAccent,
    'red': Colors.red,
    'redAccent': Colors.redAccent,
    'teal': Colors.teal,
    'tealAccent': Colors.tealAccent,
    'transparent': Colors.transparent,
    'white': Colors.white,
    'white10': Colors.white10,
    'white12': Colors.white12,
    'white24': Colors.white24,
    'white30': Colors.white30,
    'white38': Colors.white38,
    'white54': Colors.white54,
    'white60': Colors.white60,
    'white70': Colors.white70,
    'yellow': Colors.yellow,
    'yellowAccent': Colors.yellowAccent,
  };
```

You could use this to find the color name by doing this:
`colorStringToColor.entries.firstWhere((element) => element.value == Colors.blue);`

Or you could reverse the map to where the `Color` is the key and the name `String` is the value.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure whether this would be a feasible solution for you, but one way to achieve this is to extent the `Color` class and create a map with the (relevant) color values and respective names:

```
extension ColorNames on Color {
  static const colorNames = {
    0xFF000000: 'Colors.black'
    // ...
  };
  
  String colorName() => colorNames[value] ?? 'Undefined color';
}
```

Usage:

```
final color = Colors.black;
print(color.colorName());
```

Answer (score 0):

The "Color Parser" Package can help in this situation.

https://pub.dev/packages/color_parser

You can print name of the color using toName() method.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this package:

https://pub.dev/packages/colornames

```
import 'package:colornames/colornames.dart' 

final color = Color(0xFFFFFF);
ColorNames.guess(color) ; // White
color.colorName; // White

final int colorValue = 128;
colorValue.colorName; // Navy Blue
0x007fff.colorName;// Azure
```

Answer (score -2):

Try

```html
String? colorName;

if(myColor == colors.green){
  setState({
    colorName = "green";
  });
}else{
  setState({
    colorName = "another color";
  });
}
print(colorName);
```